# No Internet on Linux KVM Windows 10 guest using VirtIO drivers

Tags: linux, windows-10, networking, linux-kvm, virtio

I'm attempting to install a Windows 10 VM using QEMU/KVM in `virt-manager`. I want to use it for a WinApps setup to do some experiments with Adobe CC in Linux.

I've been following several guides including the Winapps guide on their Github page and [this medium article](https://raphtlw.medium.com/how-to-set-up-a-kvm-qemu-windows-10-vm-ca1789411760).

The setup is using VirtIO drivers, so I setup the proper CDROM devices with the virtIO drivers, as well as the `NIC` device, I loaded them at install time, I installed the rest of the drivers on the VM using the VirtIO 64-bit installer in the E: drive of the VM and everything seems to be working except for network connectivity.

I did some digging, network issues with VirtIO seem to have been very common over the years, but the issues I'm seeing don't appear to be particularly common.

The device itself in the Windows Appears to be working, there's no warning icon on it, attempting to update the driver simply tells me that the best possible driver is installed. The devices and drivers work... just no internet.

My system is Pop_OS 21.10, kernel version `5.16.11-76051611-generic`.

I would assume there's more setup to do with `iptables` and configuring ports, but none of those solutions have worked so far.

EDIT: Of course, if there is more info needed to debug this issue, I'm ready to add it, I just don't know what yet.

ADDENDUM 1: For the networking I have not made any explicit setup other than specifying the NIC virtual device to use virtIO. The virtual connection is the default NAT virtual network, which has created a virtual device listed as `virbr0` in the `ifconfig`. No network bridging has been done so far, I've setup about as default as you can go.

Also on the guest machine, all I have is just the automatically configured local IP and that's it. No access to the host machine or router, at least as far as I'm able to read it. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of guest ipconfig]

ADDENDUM 2: Here's a screenshot of the host `ifconfig`:

[image: host ifconfig]

The eno1 is my main network device, in this case connected via Ethernet. `virbr0` is configured to 192.168.122.1

The output of `iptables-save` is as follows:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar 23 14:11:01 2022
*mangle
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:C170 - [0:0]
:C171 - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j C171
-A OUTPUT -j C170
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -o lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
-A C170 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A C170 -m mark --mark 0x0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 17040 --queue-bypass
-A C171 -j CONNMARK --restore-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A C171 -m mark --mark 0x0 -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 17140 --queue-bypass
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j CHECKSUM --checksum-fill
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 23 14:11:01 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar 23 14:11:01 2022
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:C17 - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWI - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWO - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_FWX - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_INP - [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_OUT - [0:0]
-A INPUT -j LIBVIRT_INP
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lxcbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j C17
-A FORWARD -d 192.168.122.103/32 -m state --state NEW,RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWX
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWI
-A FORWARD -j LIBVIRT_FWO
-A FORWARD -o lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i lxcbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -j LIBVIRT_OUT
-A OUTPUT -j C17
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x0 -j DROP
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6a4 -j RETURN
-A C17 -p icmp -m mark --mark 0x6a5 -j RETURN
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6a5 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6a6 -j DROP
-A C17 -j CONNMARK --save-mark --nfmask 0xffffffff --ctmask 0xffffffff
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6ae -j RETURN
-A C17 -p icmp -m mark --mark 0x6af -j RETURN
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6af -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6b0 -j DROP
-A C17 -m mark --mark 0x6b5 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -d 192.168.122.0/24 -o virbr0 -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWI -o virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -s 192.168.122.0/24 -i virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_FWO -i virbr0 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A LIBVIRT_FWX -i virbr0 -o virbr0 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_INP -i virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p udp -m udp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
-A LIBVIRT_OUT -o virbr0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 68 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
# Completed on Wed Mar 23 14:11:01 2022
# Generated by iptables-save v1.8.7 on Wed Mar 23 14:11:01 2022
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:LIBVIRT_PRT - [0:0]
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.103:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.3:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.2:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.1:80
-A PREROUTING -d 192.168.100.4/32 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.0:80
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m mark --mark 0x6b5 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.17:717
-A OUTPUT -p tcp -m mark --mark 0x6b5 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.17:717
-A OUTPUT -p udp -m mark --mark 0x707 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.17:53
-A POSTROUTING -j LIBVIRT_PRT
-A POSTROUTING -s 10.0.3.0/24 ! -d 10.0.3.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 224.0.0.0/24 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p tcp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -p udp -j MASQUERADE --to-ports 1024-65535
-A LIBVIRT_PRT -s 192.168.122.0/24 ! -d 192.168.122.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

The `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward` shows the value is 1

The output of `nft list ruleset` is as follows:

```
table ip mangle {
    chain C170 {
        counter packets 329521 bytes 42983171 meta mark set ct mark
        mark 0x0 counter packets 17735 bytes 2429935 queue num 17040 bypass
    }

    chain C171 {
        counter packets 750958 bytes 581165784 meta mark set ct mark
        mark 0x0 counter packets 77401 bytes 22111093 queue num 17140 bypass
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 329521 bytes 42983171 jump C170
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 750958 bytes 581165784 jump C171
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 319891 bytes 41493267 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        oifname "lxcbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 # CHECKSUM fill
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 38 bytes 12908 # CHECKSUM fill
    }
}
table ip filter {
    chain C17 {
        mark 0x0 counter packets 2 bytes 272 drop
        mark 0x6a4 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto icmp mark 0x6a5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        mark 0x6a5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject with icmp type host-prohibited
        mark 0x6a6 counter packets 204 bytes 6120 drop
        counter packets 1076776 bytes 623890722 ct mark set mark
        mark 0x6ae counter packets 959925 bytes 591009768 return
        meta l4proto icmp mark 0x6af counter packets 54 bytes 4752 return
        mark 0x6af counter packets 27 bytes 1620 reject with icmp type host-prohibited
        mark 0x6b0 counter packets 78544 bytes 23162512 drop
        mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 320184 bytes 41688472 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
        counter packets 329481 bytes 42970183 jump C17
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 736720 bytes 567211499 jump LIBVIRT_INP
        iifname "lxcbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "lxcbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "lxcbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "lxcbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        counter packets 747501 bytes 580926931 jump C17
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        ip daddr 192.168.122.103 ct state new,related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
        oifname "lxcbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "lxcbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 3384 bytes 223947 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 35 bytes 1820 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 67 counter packets 38 bytes 13086 accept
        iifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 67 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 53 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto udp udp dport 68 counter packets 38 bytes 12908 accept
        oifname "virbr0" meta l4proto tcp tcp dport 68 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
        iifname "virbr0" ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        iifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
        oifname "virbr0" ip daddr 192.168.122.0/24 ct state related,established counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
        oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
        iifname "virbr0" oifname "virbr0" counter packets 0 bytes 0 accept
    }
}
table ip nat {
    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 127.0.0.17:717
        meta l4proto tcp mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 127.0.0.17:717
        meta l4proto udp mark 0x707 counter packets 8350 bytes 604513 dnat to 127.0.0.17:53
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 14300 bytes 1519659 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
        ip saddr 10.0.3.0/24 ip daddr != 10.0.3.0/24 counter packets 72 bytes 17932 masquerade 
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 224.0.0.0/24 counter packets 34 bytes 3499 return
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr 255.255.255.255 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto tcp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        meta l4proto udp ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 33 bytes 13696 masquerade to :1024-65535 
        ip saddr 192.168.122.0/24 ip daddr != 192.168.122.0/24 counter packets 0 bytes 0 masquerade 
    }

    chain PREROUTING {
        type nat hook prerouting priority dstnat; policy accept;
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 192.168.100.4 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 192.168.122.103:80
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 192.168.100.4 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 192.168.122.3:80
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 192.168.100.4 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 192.168.122.2:80
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 192.168.100.4 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 192.168.122.1:80
        meta l4proto tcp ip daddr 192.168.100.4 tcp dport 80 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to 192.168.122.0:80
    }
}
table ip6 mangle {
    chain C170 {
        counter packets 2937 bytes 1017495 meta mark set ct mark
        mark 0x0 counter packets 644 bytes 92091 queue num 17060 bypass
    }

    chain C171 {
        counter packets 79076 bytes 27540091 meta mark set ct mark
        mark 0x0 counter packets 75130 bytes 25982530 queue num 17160 bypass
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type route hook output priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 2937 bytes 1017495 jump C170
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 79076 bytes 27540091 jump C171
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type filter hook postrouting priority mangle; policy accept;
        counter packets 4202 bytes 1496447 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
table ip6 filter {
    chain C17 {
        mark 0x0 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        mark 0x6a4 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp mark 0x6a5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        mark 0x6a5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject with icmpv6 type admin-prohibited
        mark 0x6a6 counter packets 0 bytes 0 drop
        counter packets 81998 bytes 28555654 ct mark set mark
        mark 0x6ae counter packets 7457 bytes 2613792 return
        meta l4proto ipv6-icmp mark 0x6af counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
        mark 0x6af counter packets 0 bytes 0 reject with icmpv6 type admin-prohibited
        mark 0x6b0 counter packets 74470 bytes 25935586 drop
        mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 return
    }

    chain OUTPUT {
        type filter hook output priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 2677 bytes 923453 jump LIBVIRT_OUT
        counter packets 2922 bytes 1015563 jump C17
    }

    chain INPUT {
        type filter hook input priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 78566 bytes 27404953 jump LIBVIRT_INP
        counter packets 79076 bytes 27540091 jump C17
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_INP {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_OUT {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWO {
    }

    chain FORWARD {
        type filter hook forward priority filter; policy accept;
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWX
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWI
        counter packets 0 bytes 0 jump LIBVIRT_FWO
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWI {
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_FWX {
    }
}
table ip6 nat {
    chain OUTPUT {
        type nat hook output priority -100; policy accept;
        meta l4proto udp mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to [::1]:717
        meta l4proto tcp mark 0x6b5 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to [::1]:717
        meta l4proto udp mark 0x707 counter packets 0 bytes 0 dnat to [::1]:53
    }

    chain LIBVIRT_PRT {
    }

    chain POSTROUTING {
        type nat hook postrouting priority srcnat; policy accept;
        counter packets 245 bytes 62982 jump LIBVIRT_PRT
    }
}
```

ADDENDUM 3: The output of `nslookup` in the guest machine:

[image]

Comment: I think you need to clarity whether you are e.g. bridging your VM to the host LAN, using an "internal" bridge and relies on IP/L3 forwarding, or the qemu "user" networking. For example, you will have no internet (and host LAN) access if you want the first but forgot to enslave a host NIC to the bridge. Also check whether you are getting any (non-[APIPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address#IPv4)) IP configured on the guest (assuming option 1 and your host LAN have a DHCP server working).

Comment: @TomYan I've edited the question to clarify as best as I can. If the question requires any config pastes or screenshots, I'll be sure to add them.

Comment: I'm not familiar with libvirt, but sounds like option 2 to me. Do you see `192.168.122.1` being configured on `virbr0` in the `ifconfig` output you mentioned (I assume that was  executed on the host)? Also share the output of `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`, `iptables-save` and `nft list ruleset` (all run as root / with `sudo`).

Comment: Inside the VM, everything looks fine. You should clarify how exactly you cannot connect to what exactly. Maybe use `ping`, `Invoke-WebRequest`, … and provide the results.

Comment: @DanielB the guest machine simply has no internet whatsoever. Browser has no connection, `ping` and the likes simply time out. The network device registers as working properly in the guest though. The problem appears to be somewhere outside the guest istelf i reccon.

Comment: @IneptusMechanicus I am not seeing anything wrong in your firewall rules, except as per the counters, the forward / nat rules that are supposed to be matched when the guest try to reach the Internet were not matched at all. So the only thing I could think of is that perhaps you should also check the per-interface forwarding sysctl with `sysctl -a -r 'ipv4.*\.forwarding'`. By the way, can you also confirm that DNS queries from the guest work (by testing with e.g. `nslookup`)?

Comment: All the interfaces are set to 1. I've also added the output of nslookup in the original post

Comment: @IneptusMechanicus Hmm, have you ever tried pinging a *public* IP (e.g. 8.8.8.8)? (Btw, do you have any idea what generates your firewall rules? I just noticed there seems to be something wrong in `LIBVIRT_OUT`, but it's only about DNS queries to the host.)

Comment: So pinging works, oddly enough. But accessing the internet over the browser doesn't work and running the diagnostic tool says the DNS server isn't responding

Comment: @IneptusMechanicus That's exactly what I expect. In `LIBVIRT_OUT`, `dport 53` should instead be `sport 53`, as unlike the case of DHCP, the source/client port number of a DNS query is not a specific port, so when we match the replies from the server, we need to match its source port number (which is the destination port number of the query: 53). So fixing the two rules (tcp and udp) should get things working.

Comment: Another oddity is that I can ping the router, but not the host machine. I assume it's due to this same reason. In previous installation attempts the router timed out as well, but now, when I saw public IP-s working, i tried again and it worked.

Comment: @IneptusMechanicus All I can say is you probably need to figure out what those obscure `CXX[X]` chains are for and clean up your firewall (after confirming that nothing actually relies on them to work, maybe). The mistake in `LIBVIRT_OUT` I mentioned shouldn't actually cause any problem (as per your ruleset dump) if you don't have those `CXX[X]` chains as all the chain policies are `accept`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134996/discussion-between-ineptusmechanicus-and-tom-yan).

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the same issue you experienced, but I had a problem where I started my VM and the network no longer worked.  It had a local IP address and it could ping the host, but it couldn't ping 8.8.8.8.

It turned out that my `virbr0` network device stopped working.  My guess is that it was because the 'default' Virtual Network is set to forward to "Any physical device".  My host seems to have a bunch of those listed, but only one is my actual ethernet device.  It stands to reason that, arbitrarily, it may try to forward Guest network traffic to the wrong physical device on the Host.

To fix this, I created a new Virtual Network that explicitly forwards to my ethernet device and connected that to the VM instead:

1. In virt-manager, select "Edit" and then "Connection Details".
2. In the "Virtual Networks" tab, click "+ to create a new network:

   **Network Name**: enp3s0

   **Network**: 192.168.101.0/24

   **Forwarding to physical network**: **Destination**: Physical device enp3s0

   **DNS Domain Name**: <empty>
3. Disable Autostart On Boot for "default" network.
4. Edit the virtual hardware details for the VM.
5. Change the "Network source" for the NIC to be "Virtual network 'enp3s0': NAT to enp3s0".

Comment: Thank you! I had exactly the same issue. A suggestion for anyone unsure of which physical device to forward traffic to is to run the `route` command and check with interface is set as default.